# Xcode Project Code Changes Not Updating 100% After Save-Build-Run

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

When I make code changes to my iPhone game project in Xcode, and then do CMD-B + Enter, I expect the project to be saved, build and run on the simulator with the latest.  What is happening though, sometimes, is that it doesn't pick up a small change I make unless I clean the project and then build.

I'm a long time Java person and newish to C-based languages and it's compiler.  Can someone explain to me what is cached after each build that does this and how to change my project settings to avoid having to clean every time?  Or tell me the bad news that this is part of C development?  Not trying to bash it - I get compiled JSPs stuck in the working cache often in Java, too. :P

UPDATE:  Does this have to do with the location of my builds at all?  That's the only thing I can think of that's changed from a build config perspective.

Comment: Is your source code on your local (Mac) hard disk, or is it perhaps on a network volume or foreign file system (e.g. DOS-formatted USB stick or hard disk) ? Also what kind of Mac and what version of OS X and Xcode are you using ?

Comment: Source code is on my local machine.  It's a quad core 27" iMac and I'm using OS X 10.6.2 and XCode version 3.2.1.

Answer (score 5):

Had a similar problem, I reset content and settings in the iPhone simulator

Comment: It helps only once though, I still have to do that every time I want to build the project :(

Answer (score 2):

Seems odd to me, because I never get this problem in XCode. It's not a common issue with C or anything. The tools for C-based languages usually do this just as well as the Java ones.

Comment: Yeah I don't think it's a native C thing ... each time the compiler runs it will create a new compilation.  It's got to be an environment thing where XCode or the OS is not recognizing a file as "changed".

Answer (score 2):

Go to Product Menu and choose Clean and then choose Build. Thats it.

Comment: one should not need to clean for each build.

Answer (score 1):

In the Xcode Build Preferences make sure that "Unsaved Files" is set to "Always Save". If not, Xcode will not autosave files before building and will use the last version saved to disk.

Comment: I'm in the Build tab of my Project Settings and I don't see an entry for "Unsaved Files".  Can you elaborate?

Comment: It's not in the project preferences. It's in the application preferences in the menu Xcode>Preferences>Build

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone still comes across this (as I was having this issue today on Xcode 5.1), all I had to do was open a new tab and close out the tab I was working in. Some sort of tab bug in Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about this, But in case if you are using git, go to xcode preferences -> Source control -> General

- Uncheck Refresh local status automatically
- Uncheck Fetch and refresh    server status automatically
- Uncheck Add and remove files    automatically
- Uncheck Select files to commit automatically