# Build "dependent Project" every time in xcode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I have added a small project as "dependent Project" to my original Project. Xcode 4.2 does not build  the dependent project every time for optimization sake. So when ever i change something in the "dependent project" it is not getting reflected as long as I clean the project and build again.

Is there any way to enforce xcode to build "dependent project" every time?. I checked settings but no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as the files you modify are referenced by a build task (i.e. code file, libs, ...) by your "dependent project", the build should be triggered even when compiling the parent project. However there is a known issue when the modified files are part of a "**Copy Bundle Resources**" building phase. To avoid this, you can use a small script that only "touch" a code file inside your "dependent project".

See also [XCode Project Code Changes Not Updating 100% After Save-Build-Run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2567278/xcode-project-code-changes-not-updating-100-after-save-build-run)
or [How to have Xcode always copy files (even if they have not been detected as modified) when building?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1710167/how-to-have-xcode-always-copy-files-even-if-they-have-not-been-detected-as-modi)